# Arquillian with JBoss - How to run an .sql script at the very end to repopulate the database once all Arquillian tests have fininshed?

Tags: junit, jboss-arquillian

We have a project which uses JUnit test cases and runs with Arquillian ontop of JBoss server. When the tests run, the database tables are emptied and repopulated with the test data. 

Is it possible to repopulate the database with default data from a .sql file at the very end of the tests? 
I could call the .sql file after all tests have finished in a single test class using `@AfterClass` but this approach is not efficient as the default dataset is too large.

I would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

what you are mention here is something that it is a suite level. Currently, I am not aware that you can do this with APE that always works at test class level. In this specific case what I suggest is that you use a tool like Flyway (with Maven plugin for example) to populate everything before test run phase.